# Reference error in Visual Studio 2012 for Portable Class Library .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: .net, reference, frameworks, portable-class-library

I'm using the Portable Class Library in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate with the MVVM-pattern.

When I add my 'using' in the ViewModel to reference a .NET 4 .dll, it says:

```
The type or namespace name 'prgTest' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Additional info:

```
The primary reference "MyDll" could not be resolved because it has an
indirect dependency on the framework assembly "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the
currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". To resolve
this problem, either remove the reference "MyDll" or retarget your 
application to a framework version which contains "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".
```

How can I "fix" the MyDll.dll or make it compatible with my project?

Comment: Which assembly is the portable class library, which subset is it targetting, and what does the referencing assembly target?

Comment: Portable Class Library looks like this: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-qXuhmL_78-0/UQGexJxYJKI/AAAAAAAAAb4/AILqH6mHLJ0/s400/fworks.PNG

But the error still pops up, even when I change the project .NET Framework to 4, probably because my .dll hase .NET Framework 4 (Client Profile). I don't know how to change the .NET Framework Version of the .dll.

I have a Portable Class Library with this structure

Project: Mvvm.PCL
Project: Mvvm.Phone
Project: Mvvm.App

(Like this blog.tattoocoder.com/2013/01/portable-mvvm-light-move-your-view.html )

The ViewModel of the Mvvm.PCL should contain the 'MyDll.dll'.